# Generate uuid for all the tables in a database

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I'm working on a project in which I need to generate a set of dynamic tables using UUID as table name. All the online material helps to generate UUID for a column in the table but not to the table.

Pls help me regarding the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I hope now the question is clear.

Comment: I have been assigned to create a set of tables containing same number of columns & column name using uuid as the table name to differentiate b/w the tables and then access a table from the set and do the necessary changes @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

It beats me why anyone would want such horrible table names, this can be done using dynamic SQL.

```
do
$$
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  for l_count in 1..5 loop
    execute format('create table %I (id integer primary key)', uuid_generate_v4());
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

The `%I` placeholder for the `format()` function takes care of properly quoting those horrible names.

As a UUID is not a valid SQL identifier you are now forced to use double quotes whenever you access the table, e.g.:

```
select * 
from "2dc9502b-1e49-4c6f-9675-71a900dabc91";
```

---

A slightly nicer version of this would be to turn the UUID into a valid identifier by replacing all `-` with a `_` and use character prefix (because a SQL identifier is not  allowed to start with a number) so that the whole name becomes a valid identifier that does not need those gruesome double quotes:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  for l_count in 1..5 loop
    execute format('create table %I (id integer primary key)', 't_'||replace(uuid_generate_v4()::text, '-', '_'));
  end loop;
end;
$$
;
```

The above creates names like: `t_2b526a62_a6bc_4c3a_bd52_f0db050c485c` which is a valid identifier and doesn't need any special handling.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you by any chance have idea on how to access a table in flask sqlalchemy provided that the tablename is stored in a variable.

Comment: @AkshayBabu: no idea. I neither use SQLAlchemy nor Python

Comment: It is a valid use case - if you want to create tables at runtime and ensure that there is no naming clash, you have to use a UUID name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to rename each table name to a UUID. To do that, run:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO uuid_generate_v1();
```